# want to use linux command in awk command

Tags: linux, awk

```
 awk -F, '{"date -d \"$1\" +%s"|getline b;{print $1 "," b} }' test.csv
```

Above is my `awk command`, I wanted to use input from file and convert that into milliseconds. but when i used it it show me the current date conversion in milliseconds rather than conversion for particular input from the file.

this is my file data;- test.csv

```
31-JAN-2012
06-JUL-2009
03-OCT-2011
03-OCT-2011
03-OCT-2011
03-OCT-2011
03-OCT-2011
```

Comment: See gawk manual section "9.1.5 Time Functions".

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Presuming you mean from the epoch (Jan 1, 1970) -- `cat test.csv | xargs -n1 -I {} date -d"{}" +%s000`

Comment: This makes no sense - what is the milliseconds value of `31-JAN-2012`? There's not even an hour there, never mind a millisecond. Why jump through hoops with GNU tools to generate a timestamp in milliseconds when the input data doesn't even have resolution to an hour?

Answer (score 2):

Using the non-standard `mktime` function from GNU `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="-"
    split("JAN-FEB-MAR-APR-MAY-JUN-JUL-AUG-SEP-OCT-NOV-DEC", month)
    for (i in month) {
        month[month[i]]=i
    }
}
{
    print mktime($3" " month[$2] " "$1" 00 00 00") "000," $0
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True, and `date +%s` is also a GNU extension.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `date` command does not support milliseconds, `+%s` are *seconds*. If you are sure that consuming programs can deal with millisecond accuracy you may simply add `000` to the result of `date +%` in order to fake that accuracy.

The proper `awk` command is:

```
awk -F, '{"date -d"$1" +%s"|getline b; print $1 "," b}' test.csv
```

With millisecond accuracy

```
awk -F, '{"date -d"$1" +%s"|getline b; print $1"000" "," b}' test.csv
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` so you don't have to make the comma explicit in the `print`.

Comment: Use `date +%s000` for milliseconds.

Comment: @fedorqui Thought about that but it is longer :)

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Well, but then it would not fit into a 32bit variable any more. Not a problem as long as you treat it as a string, however might be a problem for consuming programs. I left that open to the OP. But let me add a sentence about that to the answer.